# How to group rows within a time period using Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, grouping, python-datetime

I have a `DataFrame` of some transactions. I want to group these transactions with respect to their `item` and `time` column values: the goal is to group items that are within 1 hour of each other. So we start a new group at the time of the next observation that wasn't within an hour of the observation prior (See column `start time` in `DataFrame` `B`).

Here is the data: I want to convert `A` to `B`.

```
A=
item    time             result
A   2016-04-18 13:08:25  Y
A   2016-04-18 13:57:05  N
A   2016-04-18 14:00:12  N
A   2016-04-18 23:45:50  Y
A   2016-04-20 16:53:48  Y
A   2016-04-20 17:11:47  N
B   2016-04-18 15:24:48  N
C   2016-04-23 13:20:44  N
C   2016-04-23 14:02:23  Y


B=
item    start time            end time      Ys  Ns  total count
A   2016-04-18 13:08:25 2016-04-18 14:08:25 1   2   3
A   2016-04-18 23:45:50 2016-04-18 00:45:50 1   0   1
A   2016-04-20 16:53:48 2016-04-20 17:53:48 1   1   2
B   2016-04-18 15:24:48 2016-04-18 16:24:48 0   1   1
C   2016-04-23 13:20:44 2016-04-23 14:20:44 1   1   2
```

Here is what I did:

```
grouped = A.groupby('item')
A['end'] = (grouped['time'].transform(lambda grp: grp.min()+pd.Timedelta(hours=1)))
A2 = A.loc[(A['time'] <= A['end'])]
```

This gives me one group per day: the transaction within 1 hour of the first transaction. So, I'm missing other transactions in the same day but more than 1 hour apart from the first. My struggle is how to get those groups. I can then use `pd.crosstab` to get the details I want from the `result` column.

Another idea I have is to sort `A` by `item` and `time`, and then go row by row. If the time is within 1 hour of the previous row, it adds to that group, otherwise, it creates a new group.

Comment: There are lots of questions left unanswered.  Like, grouped within one hour of when?  One hour of first observation?  What about the next hour?  Does it start when the last hour left off?  Or do we start a new hour at the time of the next observation that wasn't within an hour of the observation prior?

Comment: what is `grouped` in your code? How did you get it?

Comment: @piRSquared I added more details to the question to clarify.

Comment: @MaxU I grouped by item, I added that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set up a `window_end` column for later use with `.groupby()`, and define `.get_windows()` to check, for each `item` group, if a `row` fits the current current 1hr window, or do nothing and keep the initialized value. Apply to all `item` groups:

```
df['window_end'] = df.time + pd.Timedelta('1H')

def get_windows(data):
    window_end = data.iloc[0].window_end
    for index, row in data.iloc[1:].iterrows():
        if window_end > row.time:
            df.loc[index, 'window_end'] = window_end
        else:
            window_end = row.window_end

df.groupby('item').apply(lambda x: get_windows(x))
```

2) Use `windows` and `item` with `.groupby()` and return `.value_counts()` as `transposed` `DataFrame`, clean up `index`, and add `total`:

```
df = df.groupby(['window_end', 'item']).result.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_frame().T)
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

to get:

```
                            N  Y  total
window_end          item               
2016-04-18 14:08:25 A    A  2  1      3
2016-04-18 16:24:48 B    B  1  0      1
2016-04-19 00:45:50 A    A  0  1      1
2016-04-20 17:53:48 A    A  1  1      2
2016-04-23 14:20:44 C    C  1  1      2
```

Comment: Thanks, yes unfortunately I cannot use Hour as my grouper.

Comment: Thanks, A couple comments. In your second step, `windows` should be replaced by `window_end`, and `, right? Also you may want to use another for your `result` DataFrame so it is not mistaken with column `result`.

Comment: That's right, had been fiddling with the code while editing here, never a good idea. Should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

inspired (+1) by Stefan's solution I came to this one:

```
B = (A.groupby(['item', A.groupby('item')['time']
                         .diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()//60//60
               ],
               as_index=False)['time'].min()
)


B[['N','Y']] = (A.groupby(['item', A.groupby('item')['time']
                                    .diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()//60//60
                          ])['result']
                 .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_frame().T).fillna(0)
                 .reset_index()[['N','Y']]
)
```

Output:

```
In [178]: B
Out[178]:
  item                time    N    Y
0    A 2016-04-18 13:08:25  3.0  1.0
1    A 2016-04-18 23:45:50  0.0  1.0
2    A 2016-04-20 16:53:48  0.0  1.0
3    B 2016-04-18 15:24:48  1.0  0.0
4    C 2016-04-23 13:20:44  1.0  1.0
```

PS the idea is to use `A.groupby('item')['time'].diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()//60//60` as a part of grouping:

```
In [179]: A.groupby('item')['time'].diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()//60//60
Out[179]:
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     9.0
4    41.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thatnks @MaxU, I get `AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'` error. I have `import datetime as dt`.

Answer (score 1):

## Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """item    time             result
A   2016-04-18 13:08:25  Y
A   2016-04-18 13:57:05  N
A   2016-04-18 14:00:12  N
A   2016-04-18 23:45:50  Y
A   2016-04-20 16:53:48  Y
A   2016-04-20 17:11:47  N
B   2016-04-18 15:24:48  N
C   2016-04-23 13:20:44  N
C   2016-04-23 14:02:23  Y
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delimiter="\s{2,}", parse_dates=[1], engine='python')
```

## Solution

I needed to create a few process functions:

```
def set_time_group(df):
    cur_time = pd.NaT
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(cur_time):
            cur_time = row.time
        delta = row.time - cur_time
        if delta.seconds / 3600. < 1:
            df.loc[index, 'time_ref'] = cur_time
        else:
            df.loc[index, 'time_ref'] = row.time
            cur_time = row.time
    return df

def summarize_results(df):
    df_ = df.groupby('result').count().iloc[:, 0]
    df_.loc['total count'] = df_.sum()
    return df_

dfg1 = df.groupby('item').apply(set_time_group)
dfg2 = dfg1.groupby(['item', 'time_ref']).apply(summarize_results)
df_f = dfg2.unstack().fillna(0)
```

## Demonstration

```
print df_f

result                      N    Y  total count
item time_ref                                  
A    2016-04-18 13:08:25  2.0  1.0          3.0
     2016-04-18 23:45:50  0.0  1.0          1.0
     2016-04-20 16:53:48  1.0  1.0          2.0
B    2016-04-18 15:24:48  1.0  0.0          1.0
C    2016-04-23 13:20:44  1.0  1.0          2.0
```